# Trigger event when Combobox contains only one item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, triggers, combobox

I need disable a combobox whenever it contains only 1 item.
I spent a fair amount of time reading the documentation on the microsoft website, but I cannot see any trigger for this type of events.
Is this possible in a mvvm way?

I have several (~100) comboboxes that share the same style, so I was looking to add the trigger to the style but I cannot find a way to do this.

Any help is appreciated, even if it involves more documentation to read.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="D">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource ComboboxStyleD}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" SelectedValue="{Binding D[0]}" ItemsSource="{Binding D}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False">
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an "easy" solution for this in WPF.

```
        <Style x:Key="ComboboxStyleD" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Red"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding D.Count}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Black"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether that Binding D.Count works.

What I would do is, assuming you are binding each ComboBox's DataContext to a ViewModel property (an ObservableCollection for example), and in that ViewModel you have a **Size** property that gets updated with the amount of the items in that Observable Collection, then you could use a style with a similar DataTrigger, binding that property value and disabling the ComboBox if that is equal to 1.

```
 <Style x:Key="ComboboxStyleD" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
     <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Red"/>
     <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Red"/>
     <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Size}" Value="1">
             <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
             <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Black"/>
             <Setter Property="TextBlock.Background" Value="Black"/>
         </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

Comment: Yes, fortunatelly the D.Count works, which it's kind of what I was looking for. Regarless, thank you for your answer, which is very useful too.